# Nil not turning into null in request on Fog

Tags: ruby, openstack, fog, openstack-neutron

Afternoon StackOverflow,

I am trying to build a network on OpenStack using Fog & Ruby but the network I am trying to make is getting made with a gateway, after readying the API Documents [here](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-networking-v2.html) it says to disable the gateway on creation

> set the gateway_ip attribute to null in the request body

I tried the following with no luck

```
@openstack_network.subnets.create(:name => "my-network", :network_id => network.id, :cidr => '240.250.0.0/16', :ip_version => 4, :gateway_ip => nil)
```

I also tried setting it to `'null'` and `''`.

I'm a bit stuck on what to try and how I can do this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work over at Rackspace and help maintain the Fog gem.

I looked over your issue and found that the code automatically stripped `nil` values; so OpenStack was never hearing about your full request.

I've opened a [Pull Request](https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/3613) aimed at solving this issue.

Thank you very much for finding this three year old bug! :)